Flutter app run issue on iOS after adding videoSDK
I'm encountering a build issue when attempting to run my Flutter app on iOS after integrating the  VideoSDK. The specific error message is:
The specific error message is:
'ios/Pods/Headers/Private/grpc/gRPC-Core.modulemap' not found

I've followed the official documentation and tried increasing the platform :ios, '13.0' setting in my ios/Podfile, but the problem persists.
videoSDK Doc
've followed the official documentation and tried the recommended solutions, including:

Increasing iOS Platform Version: Set platform :ios, '13.0' in the Podfile.

Customizing Pod Installation: Implemented the following code snippet in my Podfile as suggested in the documentation:


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |build_configuration|
      build_configuration.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64 i386'
    end
  end
end

Despite these efforts, the issue persists.

To resolve the ios/Pods/Headers/Private/grpc/gRPC-Core.modulemap' not found error in your Flutter iOS app using VideoSDK, follow these steps:
1. Clean the Pod Installation:
In your iOS project directory, run the following command to deintegrate the existing Pods:
pod deintegrate

Delete the Podfile.lock file.
2. Modify the Podfile:
Open your Podfile and make the following changes:
a. Update the post_install block:
Replace the existing post_install block with the following code:
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each   
 do |build_configuration|
      build_configuration.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64 i386'
    end
  end
end   

b. Modify the use_frameworks! line:
Change the use_frameworks! line to:
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

3. Reinstall Pods:
Run the following command to reinstall the Pods with the new configurations:
pod install

After completing these steps, try building and running your Flutter app on iOS. The "ios/Pods/Headers/Private/grpc/gRPC-Core.modulemap' not found" error should be resolved.
